# Lunar Silver star text question

Tags: language-explanation, lunar-the-silver-star

> Come on, Nall! If anyone knows anything about money, it's me! Let's do
> it one more time. It'll be fun, I promise!
>
> Brett: You kids are back? Come on, now. I don't wanna win no more of your
> allowances...it just ain't right.
>
> Ramus: We want to make things more interesting, Brett. We want to bet...this.
>
> System: Bet Dragon Diamond
>
> Nall: Ramus! You better be sure about what you're doing! We didn't come all the
> way to Saith to lose the Diamond on a coin flip!
>
> Brett: Holy Goddess Althena! I reckon that's the purtiest rock I ever seen!
> You got yourself a bet, son!
>
> [He flips the coin.]
>
> Ramus: Hah! There! See?!
>
> Nall: So, Ramus' plan was to beat up Brett? Sheer genius...
>
> Brett: Put that coin down, boy!
>
> Ramus: Why, Brett? So I don't notice it has two heads?
>
> Nall: Brett, you're nothing but a lying, cheating weasel!

I didn’t understand this phrase from the game, "Put that coin down, boy!"

Is Ramus  holding a coin to show Brett is faking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has been a long time since I've played the Lunar games, but based on the presented context:

It appears that Brett is a hustler or con man, that makes bets with people using a coin (heads I win, tails you win). The con in this case, however, is that Brett uses a coin with two heads on it so that he will always win whatever bets he makes.

Based on the context, Ramus and Nall have made bets with Brett before and lost due to Brett's cheating. Ramus seems to have concluded how Brett won their past bets and wants to expose his cheating, and therefore Ramus entices Brett into another bet with the Dragon Diamond as the prize. But when Brett flips the coin Ramus grabs it and exposes that it is a trick coin with two heads on it and that Brett has been cheating.

Thus when Brett says "Put that coin down, boy!" he knows that Ramus is going to expose him and tries to stop Ramus by yelling at him to leave the trick coin alone.